# Python logic calculate time difference between two rows

Tags: python-3.x

I have input data like this

Input:

```
ID, eventName, time
1,pause,2022-10-27T18:15:47Z
1,resume,2022-10-28T08:01:16Z
2,pause,2022-10-26T22:00:01Z
2,resume,2022-10-27T08:00:15Z
3,pause,2022-10-27T04:00:26Z
3,resume,2022-10-27T10:00:20Z
4,pause,2022-10-28T09:09:07Z
4,resume,2022-10-28T07:05:13Z
5,pause,2022-10-27T09:42:14Z
5,resume,2022-10-27T23:01:00Z
```

I am expecting below format as output

Expected output:

```
ID, time_pause, time_resume, time_diff
1,2022-10-27T18:15:47Z,2022-10-28T08:01:16Z,14hr
2,2022-10-26T22:00:01Z,2022-10-27T08:00:15Z,10hr
3,2022-10-27T04:00:26Z,2022-10-27T10:00:20Z,6hr
4,2022-10-28T07:05:13Z,2022-10-28T09:09:07Z,2hr
5,2022-10-27T09:42:14Z,2022-10-27T23:01:00Z,14hr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. there are always 2 rows with the same id, one for resume and one for pause
2. the datetime format is always the same

here it is a simple attempt:

```py
import datetime

FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'

DATA = (
    (1,'pause','2022-10-27T18:15:47Z'),
    (1,'resume','2022-10-28T08:01:16Z'),
    (2,'pause','2022-10-26T22:00:01Z'),
    (2,'resume','2022-10-27T08:00:15Z'),
    (3,'pause','2022-10-27T04:00:26Z'),
    (3,'resume','2022-10-27T10:00:20Z'),
    (4,'pause','2022-10-28T09:09:07Z'),
    (4,'resume','2022-10-28T07:05:13Z'),
    (5,'pause','2022-10-27T09:42:14Z'),
    (5,'resume','2022-10-27T23:01:00Z'),
)

def _f(d):
    d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x[0])
    for p1, p2 in zip(d[::2], d[1::2]):
        id1, pr1, d1 = p1
        id2, pr2, d2 = p2
        assert id1 == id2

        d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, FORMAT)
        d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, FORMAT)
        min_datetime, max_datetime = min(d1, d2), max(d1, d2)
        delta = max_datetime - min_datetime

        yield id1, min_datetime.strftime(FORMAT), max_datetime.strftime(FORMAT), f'{round(delta.seconds / 3600)}h'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in _f(DATA):
        print(x)
```

The output is the following:

```
(1, '2022-10-27T18:15:47Z', '2022-10-28T08:01:16Z', '14h')
(2, '2022-10-26T22:00:01Z', '2022-10-27T08:00:15Z', '10h')
(3, '2022-10-27T04:00:26Z', '2022-10-27T10:00:20Z', '6h')
(4, '2022-10-28T07:05:13Z', '2022-10-28T09:09:07Z', '2h')
(5, '2022-10-27T09:42:14Z', '2022-10-27T23:01:00Z', '13h')
```

The last row is not clear as the delta is 13.31 hours (in decimal), so if rounded it is 13 hours, not 14.